# Does KCN prefer SN2 or nucleophilic addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

If we have a 1° halide that also contains a carbonyl group (like 5‐chloropentan‐2‐one), and we add 1 mole of KCN in DMSO to it, what will happen?

[image: 5‐chloropentan‐2‐one]

Will the S<sub>N</sub>2 product by substitution of chlorine or nucleophilic addition at the carbonyl carbon be the major product, and why? And does using HCN instead of KCN have a different effect?

Comment: Cyanide addition to carbonyl gives cyanohydrins but this is reversible and usually under acid catalysed conditions. Nucleophilic displacement of the chloride will predominate.

Comment: @Waylander thanks for the answer. So will the SN2 product be dominant even under acid catalysed conditions? And does using HCN instead of KCN change anything at all?

Comment: If you introduce acid cyanohydrin formation is going to be favoured https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanohydrin_reaction  To get the chloride displacement you want no source of hydrogen to protonate the cyanohydrin alkoxide, so polar aprotic conditions with KCN